# Using generic trait methods like .into() when type inference is impossible

Tags: rust, type-conversion

I'm hoping to be able to use `.into()` to convert a value in a context where type inference is impossible. This is typically when I want to convert a temporary value into some other type for passing it into a generic function. See the following code for an example ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9bf3ac22e1fbb5122ad30499d3e5070c)):

```
use std::convert::*;

struct NewType(pub i32);

impl From<NewType> for i32 {
    fn from(src: NewType) -> i32 {
        src.0
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = NewType(5);
    println!("{}", a.into()); // Understandably won't compile
}
```

I get the error:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:13:20
   |
13 |     println!("{}", a.into());
   |                    ^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for `T`
```

How do I properly tell the compiler that I want to convert `a` into `i32`?

I can get it to work right by explicitly feeding `Into` with type arguments: `Into::<i32>::into(a)`. This is more verbose and explicit than I was hoping to be able to achieve, especially in a context where I have not imported `Into` (`std::convert::Into::<i32>::into(a)`). `a.into::<i32>()` would be acceptable, but that is not where the type arguments go.

`a.into() as i32` would look nice, but this exact syntax doesn't work.

Is there a trick I am missing?

Comment: Could you not avoid the problem by writing `println!("{}", i32::from(a));`, or am I missing some obvious reason why you need `into`?

Comment: hvd: Uh, that's perfect! I should have said "something like `into`" or "`into` or `from`" or something along those lines. It is sometimes difficult to find the exact level of preciseness for a question ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You could use [`From::from`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.From.html#tymethod.from):

```
use std::convert::*;

struct NewType(pub i32);

impl From<NewType> for i32 {
    fn from(src: NewType) -> i32 {
        src.0
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = NewType(5);
    println!("{}", i32::from(a));
}
```

You can read more about it in the [docs for the `convert` module](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/index.html).

Comment: Why one can expect that there is a `From`: *"Library authors should not directly implement [the Into] trait, but should prefer implementing the From trait, which offers greater flexibility and provides an equivalent Into implementation for free, thanks to a blanket implementation in the standard library."* - from the documentation of `Into`.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin You can't expect that `From` exists just because `Into` exists. That quote is about implementing traits, not about using them. Implementing `From` gives you `Into`. Implementing `Into` doesn't give you `From`. That means that you can have `Into` without `From`. This can be seen in [a code example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?edition=2021&gist=7937926e72f0383b6c615a015b9988b2).

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex My comment is not claiming that _"`From` exists because `Into` exists"_. My comment is claiming that _"you can expect that there is a `From`, because library authors are encouraged to provide `From`"_.

Answer (score 47):

I don't think there is a better way. Since the type parameter is on the trait, not the method `into()`, the turbofish operator `into::<i32>()` doesn't work. As you said, you can make it work by using the fully-qualified-syntax:

```
Into::<i32>::into(a)
```

Note, that `Into` is reexported in `std::prelude`, which means that you never have to specify the full path, as the trait is always in scope.

Of course, there is also always the possibility to bind your temporary to a name and use the type annotation of the `let`-binding:

```
let tmp: i32 = a.into();
```

---

It might be better in the future, though! There is an [*Type Ascription for Expressions* RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0803-type-ascription.md), which was already accepted and implemented. The feature is still unstable, but if it's implemented you could write something like:

```
println!("{}", (a.into(): i32));   // still unstable :/
```

Comment: I'm not sure why I believed that I had to import `Into`. But you are absolutely right that I don't have to. Thanks :) Type ascription looks like exactly what I was imagining, but I will go for the stable `i32:from(a)` instead :)

Answer (score 9):

Apparently, this is possible on Rust nightly with [type ascription](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/23416), which seems to be a feature designed for this use case ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=35f6c2c0f733ccfe015d4d58e5cf4384)):

```
#![feature(type_ascription)]

use std::convert::*;

struct NewType(pub i32);

impl From<NewType> for i32 {
    fn from(src: NewType) -> i32 {
        src.0
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = NewType(5);
    println!("{}", a.into(): i32);
}
```

Since this is available in an experimental feature, it might be reasonable to conclude that it is otherwise missing from the language proper.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply annotate the type of the result by assigning it to a variable.

```
let b: i32 = a.into();
println!("{}", b);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can hide a function definition away somewhere to get the rest of the code to look nice.

```
use std::convert::*;

struct NewType(pub i32);

impl From<NewType> for i32 {
    fn from(src: NewType) -> i32 {
        src.0
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = NewType(5);
    println!("{}", a.get_i32());
}

mod r#impl {
    impl super::NewType {
        pub fn get_i32(self) -> i32 {
            self.into()
        }
    }
}
```