# How do I guide type inference in code that has multiple chained type conversions with an Into-like trait?

Tags: rust, generic-programming

I have some structs generated by the protobuf compiler. They share the same structure, and I made them act like generics with some traits and macros. I also added some code so I can chain `SingleResponse` construction:

```rust
pub trait Response {
    type Success;
    type Fail;

    fn new_success(v: Self::Success) -> Self;
    fn new_fail(v: Self::Fail) -> Self;
}

pub trait IntoResponse<T>
where
    T: Response,
{
    fn into_response(self) -> T;
}

impl<T, U, K> IntoResponse<K> for Result<T, U>
where
    T: Into<K::Success>,
    U: Into<K::Fail>,
    K: Response,
{
    fn into_response(self) -> K {
        match self {
            Ok(v) => K::new_success(v.into()),
            Err(v) => K::new_fail(v.into()),
        }
    }
}

struct SingleResponse<T> {
    v: T,
}

trait IntoSingleResponse
where
    Self: std::marker::Sized,
{
    fn into_single_response(self) -> SingleResponse<Self>;
}

impl<T: std::marker::Sized> IntoSingleResponse for T {
    fn into_single_response(self) -> SingleResponse<Self> {
        SingleResponse { v: self }
    }
}
```

This demonstrates the problem:

```rust
struct ConcreteSuccess {}
struct ConcreteFail {}
struct ConcreteResponse {}

impl Response for ConcreteResponse {
    type Success = ConcreteSuccess;
    type Fail = ConcreteFail;

    fn new_success(_v: Self::Success) -> Self {
        // Logic not important
        ConcreteResponse {}
    }
    fn new_fail(_v: Self::Fail) -> Self {
        ConcreteResponse {}
    }
}

fn get_result() -> Result<ConcreteSuccess, ConcreteFail> {
    Ok(ConcreteSuccess {})
}

// works as expected
fn return_response() -> ConcreteResponse {
    get_result().into_response()
}

// works as expected
fn return_single_response() -> SingleResponse<ConcreteResponse> {
    return_response().into_single_response()
}

// this function does not compile
fn return_single_response_v_2() -> SingleResponse<ConcreteResponse> {
    get_result().into_response().into_single_response()
}
```

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src/lib.rs:80:18
   |
80 |     get_result().into_response().into_single_response()
   |     -------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^--
   |     |            |
   |     |            cannot infer type for type parameter `T` declared on the trait `IntoResponse`
   |     this method call resolves to `T`
   |
   = note: type must be known at this point
```

How do I make `return_single_response_v_2` compile?

Comment: How would the compiler know what the type returned should be? You've asked it to convert from a known type (`get_result()`) to an arbitrary type (`into_response()`) and then from any *other* arbitrary type to a concrete type (`into_single_response()`).

Comment: and that concrete type is parametrized by that other arbitrary type and is visible in the signature of the function. Also, your answer leads me to think my question looks like a complaint about the compiler - It is not.

Comment: How I'm deducing it is going back from the enclosing function `return_single_response_v_2`  back towards `into_response`. I don't know how the compiler does type inference.

Comment: I mean my question very literally. `into_response` returns a `K`. `IntoSingleResponse` is implemented for any `T`. What single concrete type do you want to substitute for both `K` and `T`?

Comment: ConcreteResponse?

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Using .into() when type inference is impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41207885/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: [The duplicate applied to your situation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fdc496a39c67a61403cd4a6fabddf210)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210757/discussion-between-antonio-dropulic-and-shepmaster).